# Calling undocumented function

Tags: c++, windows, dll, hook

I need to call an undocumented function which looks like -

```
struct SomeStruct Func(wchar_t *, bool);
```

Now the problem is that I don't have the definition of `SomeStruct`. I don't need the definition of `SomeStruct` just need to call the function.

How can I call this function or figure out the size of `SomeStruct` so that I can allocate a memory of the `struct`?

My hypothesis is that I can allocate a `struct` which takes the same memory as `SomeStruct` then I can call the function and return value can be held in that temp `struct`.

As of now, it's crashing on calling this function.

Why i need this is because i want to hook this function and intercept the call whenever this happens. Now to hook a function you need to return the exact same memory to caller so that it doesn't end up corrupting a stack.

I have figured out the struct size by looking at memory returned by process and some hit and trial.

I know this can also be done by reading registers directly from stack but how that i don't know as of now.

Once i figure that out i will post the solution over here.

Comment: If this function is undocumented, how do you know its signature? Also, undocumented functions are normally undocumented for a reason. Typically, the reason is that they are not part of the official API and subject to change, which means your code might break any moment, anywhere. So if you don't mind me asking: why exactly is it that you absolutely must call this function? Especially given that you're apparently not interested in what it returns…

Comment: Why do you need the return value? How do you want to use it if you don't know it's signature? If you are not going to use the return value, don't store it in a struct.

Comment: You can't. And you can't _"allocate a `struct` which takes the same memory as `SomeStruct`"_, and hope it will work. It won't.

Comment: @PasserBy - really can and **must** allocate memory for `SomeStruct` is caller of the `Func`. caller must allocate memory for `SomeStruct` and pass pointer to it for `Func` as hidden parameter.

Comment: @MichaelKenzelI got function signature using decency walker.

Comment: @RbMm Yeah you are right. I need to have a struct of exact memory. definition doesn't matter.

Comment: in what problem do reverse engineering of this function ? and you anyway need know it exactly calling convention  and you not need return structure ? only effect from call function ?

Comment: @RbMm I knew the calling convention. To figure out calling convention is not that big a deal.

Answer (score 2):

It could depend on the compiler, but when calling a function that returns a struct, the caller allocates space for the struct in its own stack, then passes a pointer to it as a hidden argument to the callee. The callee uses this pointer to fill in the struct fields, then returns. Obviously stack corruption may occur in the callee code if the caller did not allocate enough space to hold the return value.
Then the caller uses whatever it needs from the returned struct and frees the allocated space, as necessary.

So if this is your case, then invent a `SomeStruct` large enough to not lead to data corruption, then call the function.

Comment: Yeah kinda my case. I am actually hooking this function and and do some processing before returning the value back to original Caller. I know it will be difficult and be done by hit and trial. I am looking if people know some way that can give me stack memory size of a function that it's returning.